# How To Make A function that does not Allow Same Arguments

Tags: python, function

I Want to make a function that does not allow the repetition of Same Argument. Example:

```
def Hello(*name):
    for names in name:
        print("Hello",names)

Hello("Taki", "Taki")
```

In The Above Function `Hello(*name)` can Have The Same Kind Of Arguments. Such as `Hello("Taki", "Taki")`

I want this to give an Error In stead of Giving The Output.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hello(*names):
    if len(set(names)) < len(names):
        raise ValueError("value repeats")
    for name in names:
        print("Hello",name)

hello("Taki", "Taki")
```

This relies on the fact that if there is any repeat in the values in the `names` list, set will have those repeats skipped and will have less elements than the list.

Comment: This is the answer I was thinking about. However, in general, you can't add unhashable items to a set.

Comment: @quamrana, fair enough, although I can't think of a better solution for unhashable types  other than naive compare all to all with n^2 complexity.

Comment: And that's why I gave up thinking any further about this problem.  . .

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible method:

```
from collections import Counter

class RepeatedValueError(Exception):
    pass

def Hello(*name):
    if max(Counter(name).values()) > 1:
        raise RepeatedValueError('All names must be different')
    for names in name:
        print("Hello",names)
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same as my answer with a bunch of extra steps.

Comment: Indeed, but since I had already coded it... Anyway, qumrana's objection applies to mine too.

Comment: Note that both these answers work just fine for the example data provided by the OP.

Comment: Yes. And to generalize them it would be easy to code a helper function that works on unhashable types.